# Strange behaviors of instance variables in Python 2.7 OOP

Tags: python

My code:

```
>>> class Class1:
    pass

>>> obj1=Class1()
>>> obj2=Class1()
>>> obj1.x1=123
>>> obj2.x2=456
```

Then I got the following errors:

```
>>> obj1.x2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    obj1.x2
AttributeError: Class1 instance has no attribute 'x2'
```

And similarly:

```
>>> obj2.x1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    obj2.x1
AttributeError: Class1 instance has no attribute 'x1'
```

The AttributeError is quite strange, why it says the Class1 has no attribute 'x1' and 'x2'? Python claims to be able to add fields on the fly. And I am expecting result like this:

```
obj1.x2 = None
obj2.x1 = None
```

**What's the difference between the field add on the fly and the contained in the class definition?**

Comment: What on earth is ``obj1`` and ``obj2``?

Comment: Missing an `obj1 = Class1()` in your example?

Comment: Sorry, it was in my code. I just missed in my question. Updated.

Comment: What on earth is `Class2` ?

Comment: It says `Class1 instance`, that is supposed to be understood as `an object of Class1`. So, the error message doesn't look strange to me :)

Comment: Regarding your bold Question: If you "add" (=set) a field (=attribute) you implicit call `obj.__setattr__`, if you try to "get" a field (attribute) you call implicit `obj.__getattr__`.

Comment: `obj1.x2` causes an error because `obj1` has no `x2` attribute -- you added that attribute to the `obj2` instance of `class Class1`, which does not automatically add it to the existing `obj1` instance.

Answer (score 3):

If `obj1` is an instance of `Class1` then it is adding variables on an instance-based level.

This can be seen as below

```
class Test(object): pass 
a = Test()
b = Test()
a.a = 4
print a.a
print b.a # Attribute error here.
```

If you mean to add a class level variable, apply this to `Test` directly

```
Test.a = 432
print b.a
print a.a
```

Comment: So there's a difference between class-level and instance-level variables. That's quite different from the traditional OOP thinking.

Comment: @smwikipedia only in a sense that adding variables to existing objects is strange.

Comment: @smwikipedia: The converse actually doesn't make much sense, as the case of all variables being class-level variables would result in shared state between all instances. You'd have a collection of references to a singleton class.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between the field add on the fly and the
>   contained in the class definition?

This is in class definition:

```
>>> class Class1:
    x = None
```

*Proof:*

```
>>> Class1().__dict__
{}
>>> Class1.__dict__
{'x': None, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

This at instance level:

```
>>> class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
    self.x = None
```

*Proof:*

```
>>> Class1.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x000000000241C358>}
>>> Class1().__dict__
{'x': None}
```

Adding attribute on the fly adds the attribute at the instance level not the class level

*Proof:*

```
>>> class Class1: pass
... 
>>> foo = Class1()
>>> foo.__dict__
{}
>>> foo.x = None
>>> foo.__dict__
{'x': None}
>>> Class1.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

You can add attributes to class definition on the fly too.

*Proof:*

```
>>> class Class1: pass
... 
>>> Class1.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> Class1().__dict__
{}
>>> Class1.x = None
>>> Class1.__dict__
{'x': None, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> Class1().__dict__
{}
>>> Class1().x
>>> print Class1().x
None
```